# Insert/Update data to table when table recreated in another database

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2014

So we use a software that basically creates a report by deleting a table from the database if it exists and then recreates it with the same name and then inserts data into it.

I am trying to create a trigger in the software database that would move the data from that table whenever it is recreated and append it in to another table in another database.

Example: database A has report.table1 that is recreated every time the report is ran from the software. I would like to move the data from report.table1 when it is recreated to database B into dbo.table2

so far i have this trigger, but since it is relevant to that table only, it gets deleted every time I think:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updatetbl2
ON [report].[table1]
AFTER UPDATE,INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO databaseB.dbo.table2 
        SELECT *
        FROM [databaseA].[report].[table1]
END;
```

Is there any way to achieve this? Let me know if i missed any part of the issue and I can provide more details.

Comment: SQL Server is not really designed for these types of scenarios. (Your best bet is to modify the software.) You may be able to get your solution to work by adding a [database (DDL) trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks-for-ddl-triggers) to catch report table being created / deleted and either add an after trigger at this stage or simply copy its data. (I have never done anything similar myself, this is just an idea.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Alex's comment is correct - you could create a [DDL trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15) for that table that gets deleted and recreated again.

The trick here is that this DDL trigger should use dynamic<sup>1</sup> SQL to create the DML trigger you've already written (BTW, I suggest you do some research on the [`inserted` and `deleted` tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) if you're going to write DML triggers).

Then, whenever the table is being created, your DML trigger will be created as well.

Something like this should get you going:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER Report_Table1_CreateTable
ON DATABASE   
FOR CREATE_TABLE
AS   
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(4000) = 
    '
    CREATE TRIGGER updatetbl2
    ON [report].[table1]
    AFTER UPDATE,INSERT
    AS 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO databaseB.dbo.table2 
            SELECT *
            FROM [databaseA].[report].[table1]
    END;  
    '
  
    IF EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        WHERE EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]','sysname') = 'table1'
        AND EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]','sysname') = 'report'
    )
    EXEC(@Sql)
END;
```

---

<sup>1</sup>It's not really dynamic but since you can't execute a `create trigger` directly inside another `create trigger`, you have to use `exec()` to do it...

Comment: Was headed in that direction. Thanks for the solution, it works!

Comment: Glad to help! ;-)